# Canvas Fabric JS scale only the contents on a bounding box to fit the size of bounding box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I have a few objects in my canvas that are significantly smaller than the bounding box that contains them, causing some problems for the usability of my canvas, is there a function in Fabric JS that can detect the contents of a bounding box and resize / rescale said object to perfectly fit the size of the bounding box?

I will provide an image example below of how it can look like when the contents of a bounding box is much smaller than the bounding box itself.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "bounding box"? Is it a container outside of your PaperJS canvas? Do you draw the bounding box yourself? If your bounding box is within the PaperJS canvas, you can just check the size and position with `x,y,width, height`. You can then scale items with `scale()`.